# How to use index values in typescript in an Angular Material Table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i index">{{ element.patientName }}<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="index" value={{i}}/></mat-cell>
```

I made an index variable to use the value in the type script and tried `console.log(index)` and found `undefined`.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

index: number;

constructor(){}

console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: to use template value in component you need to trigger it via click event and pass index in click event method.

Comment: Thank you. I understood what you said after seeing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let i index` change it to `index as i` . **Doc** here

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

If you need to use it inside .ts . Write the line below inside ngfor.
It will put each i to store function when you click button [ write a `store` function in your typescript before ]

```
<button (click)="store(i)"> </button>
```

Your project might not need button , use anything you want, but just see you need  `(event)` to pass value in typescript. Events can be :  `(click)` / `(change)` / `(use any event you need)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if the index value is good, I would like to use this value in the component. I'd like to know how to use the value value in the component. If I use ngmodel, it comes out undefined.